# cTAKES not running

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run cTAKES an apache open source java system.

I need it for my study and it is my first time to use Java IDE

I have been trying to get it to work for 3 days so far with no luck

I check SOF and many other websites for solutions with no luck

I have tried these steps so far

Followed cTAKES instructions, as per this link
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+Developer+Install+Guide

but did not work.

I downloaded the code to my computer and got many errors

followed many solutions in stakeoverflow and many other websites and still not working.

after many tries I dont get errors but nothing executes!!!

I don't know what to do next.

here are the screens of what i get

[image]

[image]

[image]

when i hit the Run button nothing happens

I just get this screen back

[image]

How can i run this system?!

Comment: This is pretty broad as asked. If you know nothing about Java IDEs then why use one? Use the command line instructions. You might want to consider a Java tutorial as well.

Comment: Why I use it? because it is part of my study. all i want is to get this system running.

Comment: I'm asking why use an IDE, not why use ctakes.

Comment: give me any way that work. IDE or any thing that works

Comment: Did you try the non-IDE directions? You can't just say "i got errors"--that's not how SO works.

Comment: @DaveNewton I explained the errors in other posts and got resolved, now I do not get any errors but nothing runs.

Comment: It is my first time to use Java and I was directed to use IntlliJ IDE or Ecilips and I used both aand non works